# emberjs: transitionToRoute Error no method 'addArrayObserver

Tags: ember.js

From the 'job' route I am trying to transition to 'careers' route using following code.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="job">
    <button {{action 'backToCareers' this}}>Back</button>
</script>
```

The controller with following gives '**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addArrayObserver'** ' error.

```
CareerApp.JobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    backToCareers: function(){
       this.transitionToRoute('careers');
    }
});
```

If I change the code(see below) to provide model object the error changes to '**Uncaught More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: careers** '

```
CareerApp.JobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    backToCareers: function(){
           var jobs = CareerApp.Job.findAll();
       this.transitionToRoute('careers', jobs);
    }
});
```

Following is the code of my Model and the router

```
CareerApp.Job = Ember.Model.extend({
  refNo: '',
  title: ''
});

CareerApp.Job.reopenClass({
 findAll: function(){
  return $.getJSON("http://site/jobs").then(
     function(response){
        var jobs = Ember.A();
        response.forEach(function(child){
           jobs.pushObject(CareerApp.Job.create(child));
        });
        return jobs;
     }
  );
 }
});
```

Router code

```
CareerApp.Router.map(function(){
 this.resource('careers', {path: '/'});
 this.resource('job', {path: '/jobs/:job_id'});
});

CareerApp.CareersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model:function(){
       return CareerApp.Job.findAll();
   }
});

CareerApp.CareersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   gradJobCount: function () {
       return this.filterProperty('isExp', false).get('length');
   }.property('@each.isExp')
});
```

Comment: where is `CareersRouter`?

Comment: The 'carreers' route doesn't include any dynamic segments, so this.transitionToRoute('careers'); is the way to go. Update the question with CareerApp.CareersRoute.

Comment: I have added the code of CareersRoute and CareersController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model hook is expected to return an array but you return a jQuery promise object. findAll should return an empty array which is filled when the callback is executed.

```
 findAll: function() {
     var jobs = [];

     $.getJSON("http://site/jobs").then(function(response){
         response.forEach(function(child){
             jobs.pushObject(CareerApp.Job.create(child));
         });
    });
    return jobs;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pass `jobs` to `CarreersController`, this one needs to be an `ArrayController`, maybe you have to define it manually

Comment: CareersController is already an ArrayController defined explicitly. Please see the updated question. I have added the code for CareersController